# Moose Variable names may not contain :: at

Tags: perl, perl-module, moose

So I hit this weird error.

> Variable names may not contain :: at
>   .../perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi/Class/MOP/Package.pm

The code that triggers it is:

```
override 'emitEvent::ENOTE::Final' => sub {
my ($self, $e) = @_;
my ($rval);

$rval = super();


return($rval);
};
```

I found this link regarding a bug: http://codeverge.com/perl.perl5.porters/a-very-old-bug-in-safe.pm/2018166

Is this related?

If I take the '::' out, it goes away, but really messes with the way I've been naming things, so if there's a workaround, I'd appreciate it.

-E

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`override`'s first argument must be the (unqualified) method name of an inherited method.

`emitEvent::ENOTE::Final` is not an acceptable Perl method name because Perl would take that to mean the method named `Final` in package `emitEvent::ENOTE`. If you fooled something in creating a method called that, you should fix that.

Comment: Yeah.  I was porting some other code to "Moose-ify" it.  I restructured the code while I was porting it, so it turns out that the fix was really pretty quick.  Thanks.